# itext7 C# pdf created twice

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I'm am trying to create a PDF with IText7 for C# and everything works fine, there is only this bug where sometimes 2 PDF's are created instead of one. It doesn't happen every time so my guess is it isn't a problem with my code but rather with IText7. I didn't really find anything about this issue online. Anybody know why this happens?

Just to be sure, a snippet of my code:

```
private const String Dest = "c://pdfs/";
    public static void CreateFirstPaymentReminderPdf(FirstPaymentReminder values)
    {
        String location = Dest + "FirstPaymentReminder_"+ DateTime.Now.ToString("dMyyhhmmss")+".pdf";
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(location);
        if (file.Directory != null && !file.Directory.Exists) file.Directory.Create();
        //Initialize PDF writer
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(location);
        //Initialize PDF document
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
        // Initialize document
        Document document = new Document(pdf);
        document.SetMargins(100f,75f,100f,75f);
        //create text
        //-- leaving this out for privacy reasons --
        //Close document
        document.Close();
    }
```

Comment: That's a very standard code snippet. I haven't seen the behavior where this code would lead to creating the same PDF twice. My first guess would be that the `CreateFirstPaymentReminderPdf()` method is accidentally called twice. In a web context, this could be caused by the fact that some browsers call a URL more than once, even if the end user only clicks a link once. Of course, that's not an iText or an iText 7 problem, but a web development problem.

Comment: What do you mean 2 PDF's are created? You see two files in the destination folder? I would bet your method gets simply called twice, that's the only reason that makes sense. Saying that, I think the problem is not in the code posted.

Comment: "so my guess is it isn't a problem with my code but rather with [some library]"  -  

We all say that, but as it turns out, 99.9% the problem is in *our* code. :)

Comment: @BrunoLowagie The method is called from my api when receiving a POST request, so what you are suggesting might just be the problem.

Comment: Add some logging to see how many times the method is called. If the method is called more than you expect, the culprit can't be iText 7. If the method is called only once, given result to two PDFs, then we have to take a closer look at your diagnosis.

Comment: I checked with a counter and the POST is being called twice as you said. Thanks for your help!